# Change column name for SHOW queries

Tags: mysql, show

In MySQL, is there a way to change the column name for `SHOW` queries?

For example, `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'guest'@'%';` returns one column called `Grants for guest@%`. `SHOW CREATE TABLE ... ;` returns two columns with names `Table` and `Create Table`.

If there an easy way to change these column names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to change these column names.